# Bind ComboBox to font size

Tags: wpf, combobox

I used to have a very strange control in my window to adjust the font size of a `DataGrid`. It was a `Slider` connected to a `TextBox` that displayed the current font size. If I moved the `Slider`, the font size on the `DataGrid` would adjust.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FontSize}"/>
<Slider Minimum="12" LargeChange="4" SmallChange="4"
        Interval="15" Maximum="28" Value="{Binding Path=FontSize}"/>
```

I want to replace this with a `ComboBox` that has different options for font size but otherwise works in the same way.

Assuming the above works, how would I drop in a `ComboBox` replacement?

This is what I have tried:

```
<ComboBox MinWidth="40" Margin="11,0,0,0"
          IsEditable="True" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FontSize}"
          DisplayMemberPath="FontSize">                          
    <ComboBoxItem Content="12"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="14"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="16"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="18"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="20"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="22"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="24"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="26"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="28"/>
</ComboBox>
```

But this just starts with a blank displayed item and then displays "12" (which is the default font size I am loading in my view model) regardless of which size I choose from the dropdown.

I want to start by displaying the current font size, and then I want it to allow me to actually adjust the font size.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that SelectedItem was sending a ComboBoxItem to FontSize which expected an integer.

```
<ComboBox Name="FontSizeComboBox" IsEditable="True" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FontSize}">
     <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
          <x:Array Type="{x:Type System:Int32}">
              <System:Int32>12</System:Int32>
              <System:Int32>14</System:Int32>
              <System:Int32>16</System:Int32>
              <System:Int32>18</System:Int32>
              <System:Int32>20</System:Int32>
              <System:Int32>22</System:Int32>
              <System:Int32>24</System:Int32>
              <System:Int32>26</System:Int32>
              <System:Int32>28</System:Int32>
          </x:Array>
     </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

I needed to add the following namespace to my UserControl:

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

I am still interested to know how to set the Font Size List programatically. All my attempts just led to a blank drop down being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FontSize}"
```

with

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=FontSize}"
```